# Why does left join in redshift not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We are facing a weird issue with Redshift and I am looking for help to debug it please. Details of the issue are following:

I have 2 tables and I am trying to perform left join as follows:

```
select count(*) 
from abc.orders ot 
left outer join abc.events e on **ot.context_id = e.context_id**
where ot.order_id = '222:102'
```

Above query returns ~7000 records. Looks like it is performing default join as we have only 1 record in [Orders] table with Order ID = ‘222:102’

```
select count(*) 
from abc.orders ot 
left outer join abc.events e on **ot.event_id = e.event_id** 
where ot.order_id = '222:102'
```

Above query returns 1 record correctly. If you notice, I have just changed column for joining 2 tables. Event_ID in [Events] table is identity column but I thought I should get similar records even if I use any other column like Context_ID.

Further, I tried following query under the impression it should return all the ~7000 records as I am using default join but surprisingly it returned only 1 record.

```
select count(*) 
from abc.orders ot 
**join** abc.events e on ot.event_id = e.event_id 
where ot.order_id = '222:102'
```

Following are the Redshift database details:

Cutdown version of table metadata:

```
CREATE TABLE abc.orders (
    order_id character varying(30) NOT NULL ENCODE raw,
    context_id integer ENCODE raw,
    event_id character varying(21) NOT NULL ENCODE zstd,
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events_20191014(event_id)
)
DISTSTYLE EVEN
SORTKEY ( context_id, order_id );
```

```
CREATE TABLE abc.events (
    event_id character varying(21) NOT NULL ENCODE raw,
    context_id integer ENCODE raw,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_id)
)
DISTSTYLE ALL
SORTKEY ( context_id, event_id );
```

Database: Amazon Redshift cluster

I think, I am missing something essential while joining the tables. Could you please guide me in right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Your results are totally dependent upon what data you actually have in the tables. Only you know the relationships between the tables and whether you should join by `context` or `event`.

Comment: Make sure that the `events` table only has **one entry per `event_id`** otherwise the results will be wrong. From [Defining table constraints - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html): _"The planner leverages these key relationships, but it assumes that all keys in Amazon Redshift tables are valid as loaded. If your application allows invalid foreign keys or primary keys, some queries could return incorrect results. Do not define key constraints for your tables if you doubt their validity."_

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, Thank you for the inputs. I think, it is the case of using invalid key. I revisited and now I understand that while joining, we should use the valid primary key for correct results. Thank you.